Android Studio error 'Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found.'
When I try to Sync my project, I get an unexpected error, Im combining Unity and Android Studio projects. I am using kotlin build files.
So, I am trying to merge a unity project(Some AR stuff) into an existing android studio project, as an activity. I exported the application from unity, and put the unityLibrary folder in my main projects root folder. I set the gradle to 7.5.1 to be compatible with Unity. And when I try to Sync the project, i get this error: "A problem occurred evaluating project ':unityLibrary'.

Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found."

